# Soft link to a Excel sheet created in Unix is displayed as a Folder in Window

Tags: windows, unix, symbolic-link

Created a Softlink for a Excel sheet using the following command, in Unix shared file system.

temp$ ln -s temp1/Main.xlsm Link.xlsm

But when I view the temp directory in Windows, Link.xlsm appears as a Folder. While I am able to access temp1/Main.xlsm in windows, I get a error when I click temp/Link.xlsm,

```
<Network_Drive>/temp/Link.xlsm refers to the location that is unavailable.
```

However I can access Link.xlsm using [UNC path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention)